# Why is my function checking all the checkbox while it is supposed to check only one checkbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I am trying to do a list with a checkbox in front of it using reactJS. It is checking all the checkboxes when you click on a single checkbox, while it was suppose to just check the single checkbox that was clicked. How do I fix it?

```js
const checkHandler = () => {
  if (checked) {
    setChecked(false);
  }

  if (!checked) {
    setChecked(true);
  }
};
```

```
return (
  <ul>
    {props.taskInputs.map((e) => (
      <li key={e.id}>
        {e.id && !checked && (
          <ImCheckboxChecked className="checkbox" onClick={checkHandler} />
        )}
        {e.id && checked && (
          <ImCheckboxUnchecked className="checkbox" onClick={checkHandler} />
        )}

        <span
          // className='tasks'
          className={checked ? "tasks" : "tasksDone"}
        >
          {e.taskInput}
        </span>
        <LuEdit
          className="edit-icon"
          onClick={() => props.editButtonHandler(e.id, e.taskInput)}
        />
        <BsTrash
          className="delete-icon"
          onClick={() => props.removeButtonHandler(e.id)}
        />
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As [bored-coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22176533/bored-coder) stated, you need to track the state of each of your checkboxes individually.

That doesn't mean you need N `useState`s, you could use a `Record` to keep track of all the states using a single `useState`.

```
const Example = ({ editButtonHandler, removeButtonHandler, taskInputs, ...remainingProps }) => {
    // used to hold check state of all checkboxes
    // In Typescript this would be a Record<number, boolean> (assuming id is a number).
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState({});

    // handler for checkbox event
    const checkHandler = (id) => {
        setChecked(current => {
            // if id key exists and is true,
            // set to false
            if (current[id]) {
                current[id] = false;
            }
            // if id key does not exist or is false,
            // set to true
            else {
                current[id] = true;
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        <ul>
            {
                taskInputs.map( (e) => (
                    <li 
                        key={e.id}
                    >
                        {
                            e.id && !current[id] && (
                                <ImCheckboxChecked 
                                    className='checkbox' 
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        // pass in ID to checkHandler
                                        checkHandler(e.id)
                                    }}
                                />
                            )
                        }
                        {
                            e.id && current[id] && (
                                <ImCheckboxUnchecked 
                                    className='checkbox' 
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        // pass in ID to checkHandler
                                        checkHandler(e.id)
                                    }}
                                />
                            )
                        }
                        <span 
                            className={checked ? 'tasks' : 'tasksDone'}
                        >
                            {e.taskInput}
                        </span>
                        <LuEdit 
                            className="edit-icon" 
                            onClick={() => editButtonHandler(e.id, e.taskInput)}
                        />
                        <BsTrash 
                            className="delete-icon" 
                            onClick={() => removeButtonHandler(e.id)}
                        />
                    </li>
                ))
            }
        </ul>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using the same state variable "checked" for all the checkboxes. You need to have a separate one for each checkbox.

Comment: The list is not fixed. it increases as the input increases. So I don't think it is efficient to have a separate state for each checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that all the checkboxes share  the same `checked` state variable.

you can create a copy of `taskInputs` in the child component adding for each object a property `isChecked` equal to `false` and store them in a local state `taskInputsWithCheck`:

```js
const [taskInputsWithCheck, setTaskInputsWithCheck] = useState([])
//...
useEffect(() => {
  setTaskInputsWithCheck(
  props.taskInputs.map((input) => {
    return { ...input, isChecked: false };
  })
);

},[props.taskInputs])
```

then use this function when you click to toggle an input:

```js
const toggleInput = (id) => {
  setTaskInputsWithCheck((prev) =>
    prev.map((input) => {
      if (input.id === id) {
        return { ...input, isChecked: !input.isChecked };
      } else {
        return input;
      }
    })
  );
}
```

```js
onClick={() => {
 toggleInput(e.id)
}}
```

**don't forget to map through `taskInputsWithCheck` inside your JSX instead of `props.taskInputs` and to use `e.isChecked` instead of `checked` state**

one other solution is to add `isChecked` property directly to each object of `taskInputs`, then from the child component you use it and when you click to check/uncheck it from the child component, you have to update `taskInputs` state in the parent component.
to do so, you can follow the same logic, create the function in the parent component and pass it to child as `props`.